# property 'overflow-y' from css don't show the expected behaviour

Tags: css

In my project, I create the follow DIV section to simulate an popup box:

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="header"> <span id="title"></span> <span id="button">X</span> </div>
    <div id="text"> </div>
</div>
```

Where I append the content of several pages on it, the most with content bigger than the size of the box. In this current status, the content is rendered outside the box, despite I am using the value 'scroll' to the property overflow-x, as follow:

```
#box {
    border-style: solid;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
    height: 400px;
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 90%;
}

#button {
    background-color: #99CCFF;
    min-width: 32px;
    max-width: 5%;
    min-height: 32px;
    max-height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}

#header {
    background-color: #66B2FF; 
}

#title {
    text-decoration-color: #FFFFFF;
    font: 28px arial;
}

#text {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    text-decoration-color: #000000;
    font: 24px sans-serif;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    min-height: 480px
}

.ui-resizable-handle {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

what I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

if im not mistaken,

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

are css 3 properties and if you are using an old browser they wont work.

your code works fine in chrome33, here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/Z2FMy/)

Comment: I am using Firefox 27.0.1 with Kubuntu, and try in Chrome 30 too (same OS). Do you know any solution compatible with more browsers?

Comment: Yea, dont add the -x or -y, just do overflow:scroll